# Configuring fast-swap in WebLogic fails, with a "BEA_HOME environment variable is null" AsserionError

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

In WebLogic 10.3.0, I tried adding

```
<fast-swap> 
    <enabled>true</enabled> 
</fast-swap>
```

to my weblogic.xml configuration file. (`<fast-swap>true</fast-swap>`, as specified in the instructions [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/deployment/deployunits.html#wp1053872), throws an XML error, instead. Most examples that I've found cite the method I've posted above as the One True Way. )

Unfortunately, the `weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadFastSwapClassloader` throws an error:

> "java.lang.AssertionError: BEA_HOME environment variable is null"

The `BEA_HOME` environment variable is set! I can't imagine what might be going wrong.

Comment: I'm running into this exact same problem.

Comment: I am still trying to find a solution to this problem.